# Why is lookAt not looking at specified vector?

Tags: vector, three.js

I have this three js scene: http://codepen.io/giorgiomartini/pen/ZWLWgX

The scene contains 5 things:

**Camera** - Not Visible

**origen** (3D vector) - At 0,0,0.

**objOne** - Green

**objParent** - Red

**CenterOfscene**  - Blue

objOne is a child of objParent. And ObjOne looksAt origen, which is a 3d vector at 0,0,0.

But the objOne instead of looking at the 0,0,0. where the origin vector is, It looks at objParent....?

Got any ideas?

What i want is the objOne to look at the 0,0,0. Which is the origen vector.

Any ideas why this is misbehaving? thanks.

```
THREE.SceneUtils.detach( objOne, objParent, scene );
THREE.SceneUtils.attach( objOne, scene, objParent );

var origen = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 );

var render = function () {
    objOne.lookAt(origen);
    requestAnimationFrame( render );

    xOffset += 0.01;
    yOffset += 0.011;
    zOffset += 0.012;

    xOffsetParent += 0.0011;
    yOffsetParent += 0.0013;
    zOffsetParent += 0.0012;

    camXPos = centeredNoise(-1,1,xOffset);
    camYPos = centeredNoise(-1,1,yOffset);
    camZPos = centeredNoise(-1,1,zOffset);
    objOne.position.x = camXPos*4;
    objOne.position.y = camYPos*4;
    objOne.position.z = camZPos*4;

    camParentXPos = centeredNoise(-1,1,xOffsetParent);
    camParentYPos = centeredNoise(-1,1,yOffsetParent);
    camParentZPos = centeredNoise(-1,1,zOffsetParent);
    objParent.position.x = camParentXPos*10;
    objParent.position.y = camParentYPos*10;
    objParent.position.z = camParentZPos*10;

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

render();
```

Answer (score 3):

`Object3D.lookAt()` does not support objects with rotated and/or translated parent(s).

Your work-around is to (1) add the child as a child of the scene, instead, and (2) replace the child object with a dummy `Object3D`, which, as a child of the parent object, will move with the parent.

Then, in your render loop,

```
child.position.setFromMatrixPosition( dummy.matrixWorld );
child.lookAt( origin );
```

three.js r.75

Comment: Well in the end, ObjOne will be a camera...does the camera also not support to looAt objects with rotated and/or translated parents ?

Comment: The object doing the looking must not have a rotated/translated parent. Cameras that have no parent or are a child of the scene directly support `lookAt()`.

Comment: Thanks but I need ObjOne to be a child of parent object so that while parent objectParent has a smooth perlin noise that traves big distances slow, the objOne has another perlin noise which is a bit faster. 

Is there a way with the current setup(assuming objOne is a camera) to lookAt a vector?

Or is there another easier way to add this type of camera movement (like brownian motion actually) so that the camera is still a child of the scene ?

Comment: I think my answer is the answer to your question. Parent has smooth motion. Parent's child ObjOne is a dummy object that has fast motion. Then in each frame, manually reset the camera position to match the dummy position, and call `camera.lookAt( vector ).`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected codepen:
 http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oxGpPQ?editors=0010

Now the green disk rides around its parent (the red sphere) all while looking at the blue disk (or the 'origen' vector).

Uncomment lines 163 and 164 to make the camera be at the green disk's location and have the camera also look at the blue disk ('origen' vector) while it orbits its parent red sphere.

How I accomplished this is:
1. make parent Red Mesh
2. make dummyChild Object3D (this is an invisible math object)
3. make child Green Mesh
4. make origen centerOfScene Blue Mesh
5. attach parent, child, and centerOfScene mesh to Scene (not dummyChild though)
6. attach dummyChild to parent like so: parent.add(dummyChild);

In render function:
1. Move parent around with noise function (which offsets dummyChild)
2. Move dummyChild with another noise function (which revolves around its parent position, the center of dummyChild's world is its red parent's position)
3. Stick the green child mesh wherever the invisible dummyChild is.  But since dummyChild is offset by red parent, we need to get it's world coordinates in relation to Scene, not its coordinates in red's world, so we use

```
child.setFromMatrixPosition(dummyChild.matrixWorld);
```

Notice its matrixWorld and not matrix - matrix holds its local system and matrixWorld holds its coordinated relative to the Scene or World coordinate system.
4.  Use lookAt to make the green child disk 'lookAt' the blue centerOfScene Mesh which is at the origen vector or the center of the Scene.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks! But thats not exaclty what I am looking for. If you see the original scene: http://codepen.io/giorgiomartini/pen/ZWLWgX you can see the parent(red object) moves around, and the child(green obj) follows the red obj, but also has its own movement.All that is fine...green object moves independently.but still moves with the red object. I would  only need the green obj to lookAt the origin of the world, where there is a 3dvector called origen. Right now on your pen, the green obj moves but doesnt follow no more the red obj.

Comment: Ahh, ok I got it working how you want now.  Look at my new answer above

Comment: @GiorgioMartini I updated the answer above, hopefully the code is working for you now :-)