# THREE.js Align child mesh with an independent world mesh

Tags: javascript, three.js

The mesh object "childCone_B" is a child of the mesh object "worldBox" whose orientation changes continuously randomly.

I wish to keep the xyz axes of "childCone_B" aligned with the xyz axes of the independent mesh object "worldCone" whose orientation changes periodically.

In THREE.js Rev82 the following code works OK.

```
worldBox.add(childCone_B); //... done once in initiation

//... done repeatedly in animation loop

childCone_B.lookAt(1,0,0);
childCone_B.quaternion.multiply( worldBox.getWorldQuaternion().inverse()  ); 
childCone_B.quaternion.multiply( worldCone.quaternion );
```

In the latest THREE.js Rev85 I had to change the lookAt argument into a Vector3 object.

```
childCone_B.lookAt( new THREE.Vector3(1,0,0) );
```

But now the childConeB object no longer aligns its xyz axes with the worldCone object xyz axes. Instead the alignment varies continuously and progressively but with no obvious target.

How can I restore the desired behaviour?

Comment: `childCone_B.lookAt(1,0,0);` never was correct in any three.js version. Also, `Object3D.lookAt()` does not support objects with rotated and/or translated parent(s). three.js r.85

Comment: Thanks. It must have worked by fortuitous accident in R82!  Have now found how to acheive the desired behavior - by re-setting & normalizing the childCone_B quarternion on every pass of the animation loop.

Answer (score 0):

As /u/WestLangley indicated, (i) the original use of lookAt(1,0,0) was incorrect and (ii) Object3D.lookAt() does not support objects with rotated and/or translated parent(s) and (iii) object3D.getWorldQuaternion() creates a new quaternion on every call unless an existing quaternion is supplied as argument.

The following code does the job.

```
//... one-off initiation
QQ = new THREE.Quaternion();

//... in the Animation loop

childCone_B.quaternion.set( 0, 0, 0, 1 );// .normalize() is not required.
childCone_B.quaternion.multiply( worldBox.getWorldQuaternion(QQ).inverse()  ); 
childCone_B.quaternion.multiply( worldCone.quaternion );
```

EDIT

Note here is the source code for object3D.getWorldQuaternion.  It shows that if we don't pass an existing quaternion as argument then it will create a new quaternion on every call which can degrade performance.

```
getWorldQuaternion: function () 
{
    var position = new Vector3();
    var scale = new Vector3();
    return function getWorldQuaternion( optionalTarget ) 
    {
        var result = optionalTarget || new Quaternion();
        this.updateMatrixWorld( true );
        this.matrixWorld.decompose( position, result, scale );
        return result;
    };
}(),
```

Comment: (1) You can avoid the call to `normalize()`. (2) Read the source code for `getWorldQuaternion()`. How many quaternions are you instantiating per second?

Comment: (1) I was wondering about that but had copied it from the documentation and left it in to be safe (2) Appended source code to answer, not sure what significance, ? (3) I just create childCone_B once, in initiation and then "set" its quaternion in every animation pass, as shown in the code.

Comment: ...Oh perhaps you mean that getWorldQuaternion() is currently creating a new quaternion for every call and so I should instead pass to it a re-usable dummy Quaternion which I have made (once) in initiation. ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I was referring to.

Comment: Ah thanks. So maybe I should just forget using `.getWorldQuaternion()` and instead call `.updateMatrixWorld()` and `.matrixWorld.decompose()` then prog won't have to create new `position` and `scale` `Vector3's` on each animation pass either.

Comment: Yes, think you can implement something more efficient once you understand the math.

Comment: Actually, I'd consider [this approach instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36156460/why-is-lookat-not-looking-at-specified-vector/36160110#36160110). Also see [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15734049/invert-rotation-of-parent-in-the-child-so-the-child-appears-unrotated-in-the-wo/15735090#15735090).

Comment: I see that would be useful for a child needing to use `.lookAt()` but my present app requires child object to orient parallel to a world object, so the previously-described  quaternion or matrixWorld approach is good for me.  Thanks for the excellent advice as always.

Comment: `child.quaternion.copy( worldObject.quaternion )` instead of `child.lookAt()`.

Comment: That doesn't work for my case where the parent is rotating.

Comment: One final attempt to explain my suggestion... :) Add child to the _scene_, instead of to its rotating parent. Add a dummy object to the parent. Then in the animation loop, `parent.updateMatrixWorld(); child.position.setFromMatrixPosition( dummy.matrixWorld ); child.quaternion.copy( otherObject.quaternion );`

Comment: Thanks, but my design schema requires child to be added to parent because other model behaviors depend on the standard THREE.js parent:child relationships e.g. when parent is deleted/removed/hidden/... all children must be affected likewise. It'd be too costly to redesign/rewrite/retrofit/retest.