# Three.js: LookAt with parent rotated

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have some planes, parented to an empty Object3D. Those planes are always facing the camera,like sprites. It works fine unless I rotate the parent. Three.js documentation says that .[lookAt doesn't support transformed parents](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Object3D.lookAt)
So I am trying to figure out how to solve it manually.
Here is what I have now:

```
     plane.onBeforeRender = function( renderer, scene, camera,
        geometry, material, group ){

        var worldCamPos = new THREE.Vector3();
        camera.getWorldPosition(worldCamPos);
        this.worldToLocal(worldCamPos);
        this.lookAt(worldCamPos);

        // this.quaternion.copy(camera.quaternion);//this one rotates in local space of the container
   };
```

So I a m trying to convert camera's position to the space inside which the plane lives,and use it as `lookAt` target.
The problem is,the plane is sort of looking at the camera,but it constantly flickering as if swapping rotations from default to the desired one,back and forth. I don't concatenate here anything,so I don't understand why it happens.
I would appreciate if someone could point out to more elegant solution,maybe with quaternions.

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/36160110/1461008

Comment: Have you tried this.quaternion.copy('worldCamPos.quaternion') ?

Comment: @WestLangley your hack is unacceptable in my scenario because I have hundreds of objects looking at the camera at once.